# Create a vector of values using rnorm for sample sizes stored in a different vector

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

I'm a complete newbie to R. My problem is as follows:
I have a vector of sample sizes (I put random numbers)

```
samplesizes <- as.vector(c(50, 150, 50^3, 50^4, 50^5))
```

I need to create a vector of values using rnorm for each sample size in my samplesize vector and I am not sure how to take each sample from the vector and put it as N in rnorm function. The vectors will be of different sizes and I am not sure how to store them. I was thinking that I could store them as a matrix?

Comment: You can store them in a `list`. Try `lapply(samplesizes, rnorm)` to produce the list

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to store it as a matrix though?

Comment: What, you mean one big matrix? What would its dimensions be?